# Language Override Include Site Details

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, template-override, language

I would like to create a language override for both site and administrator. The language constant I am changing is;

`RSFP_REG_EMAIL_ACTIVATED_BY_ADMIN_ACTIVATION_BODY`

The content of this is;

> Hello %s,\n\nYour account has been activated by an administrator. You
>   can now login at %s using the username %s and the password you chose
>   while registering.

I would like to include my site details in this message. e.g.

> Hello %s,\n\nYour account has been activated by an administrator. You
>   can now login at %s using the username %s and the password you chose
>   while registering.\n\ [site name] [site url] [site email address]

Is there any way I can include these so they are dynamic, i.e they change when I edit them in the site global settings? Or do I need to change this language constant every time I change my site details?

Answer (score 2):

You could probably only create such dynamic language strings with a custom plugin. You will probably need a **system plugin** that is triggered by the event **onBeforeRender** or **onAfterRender**.

When that event is triggered, your plugin should look for the contents of RSFP_REG_EMAIL_ACTIVATED_BY_ADMIN_ACTIVATION_BODY and replace it with the same + the extra information.

**Edit**: I searched for the language string and noticed that it's used by the UsersModelRegistration /components/com_users/models/registration.php
That Model has a function JPluginHelper::importPlugin('user'); that loads the User plugins. So I would start looking if there are any User Plugin events that you can hook into.